# Classic ASP loop through array with array name

Tags: arrays, for-loop, asp-classic

Hey all is it at all possible to loop through a few arrays with names like:

```
arryMaster = Array("170","180","120","610")

arry170    = Array("170","2214","1121"...)
arry180    = Array("180","3890","0090"...)
arry120    = Array("120","0200","7321"...)
arry610    = Array("610","1890","0213"...)
```

doing something like this:

```
For Each arryMasterLoop In arryMaster
    For Each arryNumber In arryMasterLoop
        if (strDeptID = arryNumber) then strGroupNum = arryNumber(0)
    Next
Next
```

The problem I am currently having with the above code is that each of those arrays are named **arryXXX** and currently its looping through the **arrayMasterLoop** with only the number and not *"arry"* then the number (ex: arry170).

**strDeptID** houses one of the **2214, 2212, 3890, 0090, etc etc** in the example above.

How can I do this loop and let it know to look in the *arry*XXX variable?

Answer (score 2):

The [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_eval.asp) function is what you're looking for to accomplish this. Here's your code tweaked to allow looping through arrays dynamically.

```
for each arryMasterLoop in arryMaster
    for each arryNumber in eval("arry" & arryMasterLoop)
        ' your code here
    next
next
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific problem, I might consider using an Array of Arrays. Are the array names always in the format: arryXXX ? Do some of the array names have a leading zero like array011? How many total arrays are you working with and how are they originally created? Just a few things to think on as you work through the solution.

Now, what you'll want is to create an Array to hold all arrays, and insert the corresponding Array in the XXX position. Easy enough, right?

```
Dim maxvalue = 9999 'this is your largest array value
Dim lookupArray = Array(maxvalue);

lookupArray(170) = arry170
lookupArray(180) = arry180
lookupArray(2450) = arry2450
lookupArray(1750) = arry1750
```

Once you've created your lookup Array, you can easily loop through your arryMaster, parse the values as the index from which you'll retrieve the corresponding Array in lookupArray. Simple enough, right?

Hope that helps!